# Show name and id both in select tag haml ruby and rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working on ruby on rails project and I need to show the id and name of option in dropdown. I tried with the following code but its showing on the name of the field.

```
select_tag "select", options_for_select(@subject.map{ |u| [u.altername, u.id] }), :multiple => true
```

English(457865)
Math(7895452)

Like this, I want to show

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try following, with [select](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/select)

```
f.select "select", @subject.map{ |u| ["#{u.altername}(#{u.id})", u.id] }, :multiple => true
```

with [select_tag](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/select_tag)

```
select_tag "select", options_for_select(@subject.map{ |u| ["#{u.altername}(#{u.id})", u.id] }), :multiple => true
```